# HttpHandler Listen for Client Disconnect?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, httphandler, abort

Does an `HttpHandler` listen for a disconnect from the browser?

My guess is "no" since it seems to be mostly/only used for dynamic file creation, so why would it?

But I can't find an answer in the docs or goog.

Many thanks in advance!

**Background**

I'd like to "abort" an HttpHandler because currently, I allow huge excel exports (~150k sql rows, so ~600k html lines).  For reasons almost as ridiculous as the code, I have a query that fires for as many sql rows that the user tries to export.  As you can imagine, this takes a very long time.

I think I'm getting backed up with worker processes because users probably get frustrated with the lag, and try again with a smaller result.  I currently flush the worker procs automatically every 30 min, but I'd rather cleanup more quickly.

I don't have the time to clean up the sql right now, so I'd like to just listen for an "abort" from the client and kill the handler if "aborted".

Comment: @jgauffin I'm not too sure what the .net equivalent is, but php has this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php and I'm guessing most .net pages have the same.  does an `HttpHandler` listen to a client disconnect?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: ASP.NET exposes [Request.IsClientConnected](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BAsp.net%5D+isclientconnected). This can be used with a worker thread to create an abort-able request for a "black box" report generator in many cases. If the report generator can be directly modified to be cooperative (ie. periodically check the state) then it could poll this itself without need of a secondary thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're hoping to accomplish by listening for a client connection drop won't really help solve your problem at all. The core of your problem is a long running task being kicked off in an HttpHandler directly.

In this case, even if you could listen for a client disconnect it wouldn't ever be acted upon as your code will be too busy executing to listen for it.

The only way to properly determine progress and perform actions during long running processes such as this is to ensure that your code is multi-threaded. The problem with doing this in ASP.NET for long running processes is they'll [suck up threads from the thread pool](http://www.codedistillers.com/tja/2012/04/06/some-thoughts-on-asp-net-threadpool-threads-asynchronous-execution-and-tpl/) needed to serve your pages. This could result in your website hanging or responding very slowly, as you've been experiencing.

I would recommend writing a Windows Service to handle these long running jobs and having it spit the results into a staging directory. I would then use [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or similar to throw the request to the service for processing.

Ultimately, you want to get this long running thread outside of ASP.NET where you can take advantage of the benefits that multi-threading can offer you. Such as, the ability to report back the progress and to abort when needed.

Comment: lol.  check for telling me "'no' to `HttpHandler`s listening for client disconnects".  looks like i'm going to have to suck it up and fix the sql.  thanks fraz!

Comment: Using `new Thread` will not use the thread pool - this is viable solution (along with polling thread-Join and IsClientConnected and an icky non-cooperative thread-Abort) to be able to abort long-running report generations. Is this the "right way"? Arguably 1) Abort is icky, and should only be used when a cooperative method is not feasible and 2) use a[n existing] Report queue .. but it *is possible* to implement sufficiently "OK". In IIS 7.5 the Response.IsClientConnected works as expected when used in a polling fashion.

Comment: And if the worker thread ignores/stuffs the Abort exception (which it might) then it is no worse (assuming resources are correctly disposed with `using`, etc) than having non-cancelled generations as in both of these cases the "work must run to completion". (But if the Abort exception is being stuffed or the report generation code leaks resources like a sieve then there are other problems.)